# Meshlabserver on MacOS won't work

Tags: meshlab

I'm trying to use **Meshlab** to batch process OBJ files (quadric edge decimation, save out a smaller file). But every time I try to launch **Meshlabserver** through **Terminal** I get an error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @path/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL
>     Referenced from: /Applications/meshlab.app/Contents/MacOS/meshlabserver
>     Reason: image not found
>   Trace/BPT trap: 5

I did some research, and it looks like a couple of years ago (2012/2013) there was a bug in **Meshlab** where it was compiled to look for Qt libraries in the wrong location. However, I am on the newest version of Meshlab (2016.12), and I'm still getting this error.

Can anybody help? Full disclosure: I am an extremely amateur coder. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/64

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a bug in `meshlab`, which is already tracked in their [bug tracker](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/64). In this thread they also propose a temporary work-around. Running the following commands should get meshlab to work:

```
cd /Applications/meshlab.app/Contents/MacOS
install_name_tool -add_rpath "@executable_path/../Frameworks" meshlabserver
```

As far as I understand, this command needs to be run once, after which starting `meshlabserver` works without problems.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on OsX 10.12.6 with meshlabserver v2016.10 (and the same error)

```
$ cd /Applications/meshlab.app/Contents/MacOS;
$ export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=../Frameworks;
$ ./meshlabserver
```

Comment: Can you edit the format to make this a little easier to read?

Answer (score 1):

This workaround based on [Markus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46818978/1911852) worked for me on MeshLab v2016.12 on MacOS 10.13.3 (otherwise I got the error, `./meshlabserver: No such file or directory`):

```
export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/meshlab.app/Contents/Frameworks
/Applications/meshlab.app/Contents/MacOS/meshlabserver -i ...
```

I used absolute paths so that I could run this from any location and supply relative paths for input/output files.